# Nested JSON parsing in Logstash

Tags: logstash

I have following JSON as an input to my Logstash pipeline:

```
{
  "action": "UPLOAD",
  "who": "123",
  "when": "2016 Jun 14 12:00:12",
  "data": {
    "doc_id": "2345",
    "doc_name": "xyz.pdf"
  },
  "header": {
    "proj_id": "P123",
    "logtype": "userlogs"
  },
  "comments": "Check comments"
}
```

I would like to perform following operations:

1) **Parse this JSON -** Such that I have a new field "user" with value as concatenation of static string "User-" with "who" field in JSON. For example - "User-123"

2) **Store only relevant fields in ES** - Such as action, who, when, header.proj_id, header.logtype in ElasticSearch. And leave rest of the fields without storing them.

I tried using the following config but currently it stores all fields of my JSON into Elastic Search.

```
input {
    rabbitmq {
        type => "businesslogs"
        host => "localhost"
        exchange => "auditexchange"
        exchange_type => "fanout"
        queue => "auditqueue"
        auto_delete => false
        durable => true
        ack => true
        codec => json
    }
}

output {
    if [type] == "businesslogs" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "businesslogs"
            document_type => "%{action}"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `mutate` filter to add/remove some fields to/from your event:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            "user" => "User-%{who}"
        }
        remove_field => ["data", "comments"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!...It worked for me. Also is there a possibility that I can specify a field to be used just as a temporary variable and not to store into ES. For example - Can I use "action" field just for specifying "document_type" of ES and not to use it as a field to be indexed.

Comment: Yes, you can either add a field and then remove it, or simply create a `[@metadata][tmp_field]` field and it won't be saved in ES.